# After update trying to connect to wireless but I am already connected wired

Tags: 12.04

After update 09. or 10.10.2013 Ubuntu 12.04 (Xubuntu) It is trying to connect to wireless but I am already connected wired.

Comment: Then, why don't disable Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Wi-Fi in your network settings.